# Optimized large prime generator in C++ for embedded devices

Tags: optimization, embedded, rsa, generator, primes

Is there any stand-alone OPTIMIZED large prime number generator implementation in C or C++ for embedded devices (I need it for generating RSA keypairs) ?
I've tested several libraries e.g. polarSSL, sharkSSL or yaSSL, but non of them are fast enough, so I'm seeking for a better solution.

Comment: Correctly generating a key pair takes a long time even on powerful desktop CPUs because of the need to collect lots of random data. Why do you need it to be so fast? Generally this is a one-off operation...

Comment: If you look at the code for prime generation you will see that it is pretty damn optimized already -- But testing for primarity _is_ costly and big primes are thin on the ground.  The ARM cores will run this code pretty efficiently, so I doubt that you'll get a better in device solution.  I do have to ask:  why are you generating RSA keypairs on an embedded device often enough for runtime to be an issue?

Comment: There's room of improvement in polarSSL -- eg. in primality test, one should store remainders of small primes and increment them by 2 as one goes on. It's likely an order of magnitude less important than improving Rabin-Miller implementation, but it tells me something about the level of optimizations. Also one could speed up remainder calculation by divide && conquer tech (calculating remainders of (p_i * p_i+1 * ... p_i+3).

Comment: You can try *Tom's Fast Math*, but I think that the `GPG` source is better.  `GPG` uses assembler for `multi-word` arithmetic for various architectures and it has good algorithms.  Use of the `carry` can speed up many of these algorithms.